# Tool or usage example to generate and view SAS (Shared Access Signatures) of both Azure Block Blob and Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, fileshare

I am looking for a tool or usage example to generate and view SAS (Shared Access Signatures) of both Azure Block Blob and Azure File Share. There are lots of examples for Block Blob and Containers but what about Azure File Share SAS examples or tools.

Comment: It took me a while, but I finally found a tool that generates SAS for Azure File Share and it also lets you view the content.
EverDir.com

Answer (score 5):

Ability to create `Shared Access Signature` on a `File Service Share` is announced in the latest version of REST API. You must use `Storage Client Library 5.0.0` for that purpose.

First, install this library from [`Nuget`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/):

> Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 5.0.0

Then the process of creating a SAS on a File Service Share is very much similar to creating a SAS on a blob container. Please see sample code below:

```
    static void FileShareSas()
    {
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
        var share = fileClient.GetShareReference("share");
        var sasToken = share.GetSharedAccessSignature(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePolicy()
            {
                Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePermissions.List,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1))
            });
    }
```

In the above code, we're creating a SAS with `List` permission that will expire one day from current date/time (in UTC).

Also if you're looking for a tool to do so, may I suggest you take a look at [`Cloud Portam`](http://cloudportam.com/features/storage/file-service) (Disclosure: I am building this tool). Recently we [released the functionality to manage SAS on a Share](http://blog.cloudportam.com/cloud-portam-updates-azure-storage-file-service-and-blob-service-enhancements/).

Comment: Thanks! EverDir.com was also very helpful and the code you just posted works!